# Way to not duplicate codes between "models.py" and "forms.py"?

Tags: django

I'm writing a custom User model field.

While I was doing this, I realized I am duplicating codes between "models.py" and "forms.py"??

For example:

**models.py**

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
    )

    full_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=64,
    )
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name']

...
```

**forms.py**

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    error_css_class = 'error'
    required_css_class = 'required' 

    email = forms.EmailField(
        label=_("Email"),
    )
    full_name = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Full Name"),
    )
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        label=_("Password"),
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        label=_("Password (again)"),
    )
...
```

Here, I find myself defining the fields twice, but I don't know if if this is necessary, and if it is not, then how I can combine the two fields in one line :(

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen the [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) class? is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @DavidRobinson YesYes that's actually what I first found, but what about the "password2" field..?? I don't think it's wise to include that in the model field..

Comment: @DavidRobinson And also, what do I do with the labels for each form when I use ModelForm..? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

A ModelForm can have fields that are model-bound and unbound. You can also override the label attribute for a model field without having to re-define the field in your form:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser

    error_css_class = 'error'
    required_css_class = 'required' 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['full_name'].label = _("Full Name")

    password2 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        label=_("Password (again)"),
    )
```

Although, I don't see where you're providing labels for any of your model fields differently in your form. You can always add the label attribute at the model level too:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(u'Email Address', max_length=255, unique=True,
        db_index=True)
    full_name = forms.CharField(u'Full Name', max_length=64)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name']
```